# How do i get the row and column of value that i am looking for in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have two [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)s. One looks like the following:

```
     114.5     113.5     112.5     111.5     
36.5 1493      1651      1696      1918    
35.5 1074      1336      1794      1891
33.5 358       549       609       815
```

and the other one looks like this:

```
     elevation
1    1651
2    549
3    ...
```

now I want to my new [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) to be like this :

```
    elevation longitude    Latitude 
1    1651     113.5        36.5 
2    549      113.5        33.5     
3    ...
```

Should I loop through it? If so, how and how do i get the row names and column names to attach and be changed to numeric values?

Comment: another option `merge(melt(as.matrix(df1)), df2, by.x = "value", by.y = "elevation")`

Comment: What is wrong with my code?  It shows using only base R functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the first dataframe in a long format and then do a join.

Using `tidyverse` functions this can be done as :

```
df1 %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('latitude') %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -latitude, values_to = 'elevation', 
                      names_to = 'longitude') %>%
  dplyr::right_join(df2, by = 'elevation')

#  latitude longitude elevation
#  <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
#1 36.5     113.5          1651
#2 33.5     113.5           549
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert to `matrix` and then use `melt` to return 3 column data.frame and then subset that data.frame based on the value in second data.frame

```
library(reshape2)
out <- subset(melt(as.matrix(df1)), value %in% df2$elevation)[3:1]
names(out) <- c('elevation', 'longitude', 'Latitude')
out
#  elevation longitude Latitude
#4      1651     113.5     36.5
#6       549     113.5     33.5
```

---

Or if we choose to do this only with `base R`

```
out <- subset(as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(df1)), Freq %in% df2$elevation)[3:1]
names(out) <- c('elevation', 'longitude', 'Latitude')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`114.5` = c(1493L, 1074L, 358L), `113.5` = c(1651L, 
1336L, 549L), `112.5` = c(1696L, 1794L, 609L), `111.5` = c(1918L, 
1891L, 815L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("36.5", "35.5", 
"33.5"))

df2 <- structure(list(elevation = c(1651, 549)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```